# Evaluating area D using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Let $D$ be the region in the xy-plane bounded on the left by the line $x=2$ and on the right by the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 16$. Evaluate 
$$\iint (x^2 + y^2)^{-3/2}dA$$

Comment: Show us your work so far.

Comment: I don't feel right finishing my answer if you have not shown what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll first remind you of polar coordinates:
$$x=r\cos(\theta)\\
y=r\sin(\theta)$$
That means that $x^2+y^2=r^2.$
First, sketch your region. You will get something like the following (excuse my bad drawing):
[img http://puu.sh/lRm2G/17d858184a.png](http://puu.sh/lRm2G/17d858184a.png)
When you are integrating, your $r$ bounds will be starting from $x=2$ and ending at $x^2+y^2=16$. Let's convert to polar coordinates to get these as functions of $\theta$:
$x=2\rightarrow r\cos(\theta)=2\rightarrow r=\frac{2}{\cos(\theta)}$
$x^2+y^2=16\rightarrow r=4$
$\theta$ bounds are a little more tricky. Plug $x=2$ into the circle equation to get $4+y^2=16$, therefore the intersections of $x=2$ and $x^2+y^2=16$ are $(2, \pm\sqrt{12})$ To find the angle made, make a right triangle to get:
$$\theta=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{12}}{2}=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$$
So your theta bounds are $\theta\in\big[-\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3}\big]$.
Turning the function you're integrating into polar coordinates, we get our set up integral:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\frac{2}{\cos(\theta)}}^{4}\big(r^2\big)^{-\frac{3}{2}}r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\frac{2}{\cos(\theta)}}^{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{r^3}\bigg)r\,dr\,d\theta.$$
I assume you can go from here.

Comment: I totally get it now! Thank you. I knew how to do most of the question but I just had difficulty finding the lower bound for r.

Comment: Cheers :) Remember to mark resolved if it's resolved. Also, I forgot the polar coordinate stretch factor; don't do that! It's an all-too-common necessary mistake.

Comment: I would totally but I'm new to this site and don't know how to navigate xD

Comment: Scroll to the top of the answer you like and press the check button.

Answer (score 0):

Each arc of radius $r$ has length $2r\arccos\!\left(\frac2r\right)$

[image]

Since $\mathrm{d}A=2r\arccos\!\left(\frac2r\right)\mathrm{d}r$, the integral is
$$
\int_2^4\frac1{r^3}\left[2r\arccos\!\left(\frac2r\right)\right]\mathrm{d}r
$$
Substitute $\frac2r=\cos(\theta)$ and integrate by parts.